# Does this function have closed form?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, reference-request

Define $$f(p,n)=\sum_1^n s_i$$ where $s_i$ is defined as the maximal integer value such that $i= p^{s_i}r_i$ for integer $r_i$.
For example, we'd have $$f(2,15)=\sum_1^{15} s_i=1+2+1+3+1+2+1=11.$$

Does this function have any closed form? Or any faster algorithm than the one like the example? or any asymptotic formula？

Comment: With $p=2$ it is in the [oeis](http://oeis.org/A005187).

Comment: With $p=3$ it is again in the [oeis](http://oeis.org/A120514).

Comment: @vadim123, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that $p$ is prime and $r_i$ is relative prime to $i$, so $s_i$ is equal to $\nu_p(i)$, the $p$-adic valuation at $i$. Therefore

$$f(p,n)=\sum_{i=1}^n\nu_p(i)=\nu_p(n!)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\biggl\lfloor\frac n{p^k}\biggr\rfloor\,,$$

by [De Polignac-Legendre formula.](http://oeis.org/wiki/De_Polignac%E2%80%93Legendre_formula)

Comment: Thank you for answer, actually, it is a very beautiful formula

Answer (score 2):

We can solve this by considering the sum "sideways" in a sense. How many elements of the sum are at least one $1$? Well, every integer $1\leq i \leq n$ which $p$ divides is greater $1$ - so there are $\left\lfloor \frac{n}p\right\rfloor$ such elements, each contributing $1$ to the sum. How many elements of the sum are greater than $2$? Those that $p^2$ divides - so there are $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^2}\right\rfloor$ of those - each of which contributes an additional $1$ to the sum (since we already counted them once). Terms that $p^3$ divides contribute an extra $1$. We can continue likewise to determine that the sum equals
$$f(p,n)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor$$
which, of course, only needs to be computed up to the first $p^k>n$.

We could also express the same idea as a recurrence
$$f(p,n)=\left\lfloor\frac{n}p\right\rfloor+f\left(p,\left\lfloor \frac{n}p\right\rfloor \right)$$

(A nice aside here is that computing sums this way is analogous to using a Lebesgue integral - where we measure the sets of "how much is $f(i)>n$?")

Comment: Good, let us wait for more answers or comments,although I intend to select this as answer to my question.

Comment: I have no idea about "(A nice aside here is that computing sums this way is analogous to using a Lebesgue integral - where we measure the sets of "how much is f(i)>n?")", could you give an example?

Comment: @XL It's just the more general intuition that, if we wish to compute a sum, it just as equally valid to sum up elements, one at a time (i.e. splitting the sum "vertically") and to take the sum by figuring out how many elements contribute at least $1$, how many contribute at least $1$ additional point, how many contribute $1$ beyond that, etc.. It's a a somewhat abstract remark which you can ignore - but it plays into some important concepts in higher mathematics, where it is far easier to split the sum by "How many elements are at least $2$?" than "Let's sum the terms, one by one!"